# Ubuntu hardware wireless switch has no effect after suspend and 13.10 upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, sleep

I'm posting this on SU after it stalled on askubuntu. I hope someone here can help! If you'd prefer to answer on AU itself, here's the link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/365177/hardware-wireless-switch-has-no-effect-after-suspend-and-13-10-upgrade

Wireless works fine after a reboot, but after a suspend the hardware switch (for my laptop this is `f12`) has no effect on the wireless, it is just permanently off, and shows that it is with a red LED.

My `rfkill list all` reads:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
```

Any combination with `rfkill <un>block wifi` doesn't work, although *one time* first `block`ing then `unblock`ing actually turned it on again.

`sudo lshw -C network` reads:

```
    *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 78:e4:00:65:2e:3f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.11.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:90100000-9010ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: c8:0a:a9:89:b4:30
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90010000-90010fff memory:90000000-9000ffff memory:90020000-9002ffff
```

Also, adding a `/etc/pm/sleep.d/brcm.sh` file as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240929/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-after-suspend-and-other-hardware-buttons) simply prevents the laptop from suspending **at all**, which of course is no good.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107899/wireless-doesnt-work-after-suspend-on-a-centrino-wireless-n-130-on-a-samsung-nc) has an answer urging to install the original driver, but it wasn't an "accepted answer" so I'd rather not take a chance on it. Also I'll admit I'm a bit lost on that and would like help doing so with the specific information I've given.

I would be happy to provide more information, so long as you're willing to help me find it for you! This is a very annoying bug.

I have a `Compaq Presario CQ62`.

**Edit**. Output of `lspci | grep Network`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

**Edit**. This morning, I had had the laptop suspended all night, and then when I tried to awake it, it simply wouldn't. It would try, and then it would sleep again (I guess it felt a little bit like me! `</badjoke>`). Is it possible these problems are related?

**Edit**. I don't have enough reputation on SU proper to post links to pastebins and other questions I've tried, so I'm putting them in comments, and of course they're available in the original question.

Comment: I tried the contents of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153092/cant-find-intel-wireless-n-1000-after-waking-from-sleep?rq=1), and it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried to reload bios defaults (or something) as shown by [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB2-oaePlKc). Didn't work.

Comment: Here are pastebins of my [`lsmod`](http://pastebin.com/QGeTSfXU), [`dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/QGeTSfXU), [`iwconfig`](http://pastebin.com/c01UAFGn), and [`nm-tool`](http://pastebin.com/QtQHaKkW), all produced while the bug was in effect.

Comment: This guy is having a similar problem: http://superuser.com/questions/451769/cannot-enable-wireless